# TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python-2.7

I m working with `viewlets`. My idea is to override the default plone site with my things like my own logo, my menus, my address bar ,etc.  I used the default `viewlet` code in to my own `createPictMenu.py` file. The code which is in `brundelre3/eggs/plone.app.layout-2.3.4-py2.7.egg/plone/app/layout/viewlets/common.py ->class LogoViewlet(ViewletBase):`

My createPictMenu.py looks like this

```
class bdrMenuView(LogoViewlet):
    template = ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/main_page.pt')

    def __init__(self, context, request, view, manager=None):
        super(ViewletBase, self).__init__(context, request)
        self.__parent__ = view
        self.context = context
        self.request = request
        self.view = view
        self.manager = manager

    def main_page(self):
        return self.template()
```

Here LogoViewlet is the class which i inherit from common.py which is under eggs folder.
It successfully replaces the plone.logo with my menus. I saw it under `localhost:8086/brundelre3/@@manage-viewlets`

But when i run my project `localhost:8086/brundelre3/main_page.html` its showing error

Error Message :

```
2013-08-14 11:18:19 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1376459299.050.254417887359 http://localhost:8086
/brundelre3/main_page.html
Traceback (innermost last):
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 115, in publish
Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 501, in traverse
Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 346, in traverseName
Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 116, in publishTraverse
Module zope.component._api, line 120, in queryMultiAdapter
Module zope.component.registry, line 238, in queryMultiAdapter
Module zope.interface.adapter, line 532, in queryMultiAdapter
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong with this code?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause of your exception, but I think you're doing your `super` call wrong. The first argument should be the current class, which appears to be named `bdrMenuView`, not `ViewletBase`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145059/type-error-init-takes-exactly-5-arguments-3-given and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078926/typeerror-init-takes-exactly-3-arguments-5-given-in-eggs-directory

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues, but without more information it's hard to know exactly which one is causing this error. My guess is that it's the line with `super` that's not passing the `view` parameter when it should be. I believe there's also a typo here (should be `super(bdrMenuView, self)`, not `super(ViewletBase, self)`).

Try out this revised version:

```
class bdrMenuView(LogoViewlet):
    template = ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/main_page.pt')

    def __init__(self, context, request, view, manager=None):
        super(bdrMenuView, self).__init__(context, request, view)
        self.__parent__ = view
        self.context = context
        self.request = request
        self.view = view
        self.manager = manager

    def main_page(self):
        return self.template()
```